# 10x10 divided into the most number of rectangles of different area

Tags: mathematics, geometry

How can a 10x10 be divided into rectangles such that there are as many as possible and they all have different area? Can you find multiple solutions that are not mirror/rotation of each other?

Good luck!

Comment: so it must be divided into only rectangles, all be used, and all rectangles must have integer sizes?

Comment: @Jasen that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution:

> ```
>  2 I I I I I I I I I
>
>  2 I I I I I I I I I
>
>  3 C C C C E E E E E
>
>  3 C C C C E E E E E
>
>  3 C C C C E E E E E
>
>  A A A A A A A A A A
>
>  1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
>
>  4 4 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
>
>  4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6
>
>  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6
> ```
>
> This uses 13 rectangles, of sizes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18.

Proof that this is the maximum:

> Note that we can't use sizes 11 and 13: that would require 1x11 and 1x13 rectangles which are too large to fit in a 10x10. So we take the least 14 rectangles that are possible: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16. But those give a sum of 112 so we can conclude that 14 rectangles couldn't fit in a grid with 100 squares.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with different sizes of rectangles.

> ```
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
> |1|2 _|7 _ _ _ _ _ _|
> |4 _ _ _|6 _ _ _ _ _|
> |3 _ _|5 _ _ _ _|10 |
> |14 |16     |8  |   |
> |   |       |   |   |
> |   |       |   |   |
> |   |_ _ _ _|_ _|_ _|
> |   |15       |9    |
> |   |         |     |
> |_ _|_ _ _ _ _|_ _ _|
> ```
>
> 13 rectangles with sizes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16